# Каков вид придаточного в данных сложноподчиненных предложениях: придаточное обстоятельственное места или определительное?

Tags: пунктуация, спп, сложное-предложение, придаточное-предложение

Объясните, пожалуйста, какие придаточные в данных предложениях. От какого слова нужно задавать вопрос, в особенности во втором предложении?

1. Умолк аул, где беззаботно недавно слушали певца.
2. На горах, под метелями, где лишь ели одни вечно зелены, сел орел в тень под елями.

Answer (score 1):

1. ***Умолк аул, где беззаботно недавно слушали певца.***

Схема: […аул], (где…). Придаточное определительное, какой аул? Опорное существительное «аул», союзное слово где (= в котором),  указательного слова нет (тот аул).

2. ***На горах, под метелями, где лишь ели одни вечно зелены, сел орел в тень под елями.***

Схема: [ На горах…(где…)…]. Придаточное определительное, на каких горах? Опорное существительное «на горах», союзное слово где (= на которых), указательного слова нет (на тех горах).

Под метелями – уточняющее обстоятельство, придаточное относится к существительному «на горах».